# Tool for convert bitbucket and github tracked issues into PDFs

Tags: pdf, version-control, parser, pdf-generation

Can anyone recommend a simple tool or commonly-used script that can be used to go through all of the issues tracked in a bitbucket repo and convert each into a PDF for local storage?

I have access to ubunutu 16.04 and windows 10. As for paying, if there is nothing free and opensource, I'll probably just use google chrome's print feature to convert each issue page to pdf.

Comment: If you can find a set of options to `wget` so that it downloads all the issues for you, you can then convert the HTML page for each issue to a PDF with WeasyPrint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirements by using the following steps.

1. Get all the issue ids using the REST api of GitHub or Bitbucket.
   GitHub: https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/ 
   Bitbucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/issues-resource-296095191.html
2. With the ids you may recursively convert the URL of an issue to PDF by using the Syncfusion HTML to PDF converter.
   GitHub: [https://github.com/{{user_name}}/{{repository_name}}/issues/{{issue_id}}](https://github.com/%7B%7Buser_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Brepository_name%7D%7D/issues/%7B%7Bissue_id%7D%7D) 
    
   Bitbucket: [https://{{site}}.bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/{{issue_id}}](https://%7B%7Bsite%7D%7D.bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/%7B%7Bissue_id%7D%7D)

More details about the Syncfusion HTML to PDF can be get through the below link. 
https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf/html-to-pdf

If the issues are protected, then get the details of the issues through the above api and create the PDF from scratch. Refer the below link to create the PDF from scratch.
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/getting-started

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million US Dollars in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.